# Monotony of product of functions

Tags: functions, monotone-functions

Is there any theorem that states something about the monotony of a product of functions? Let's say $f$ and $g$ are stictly increasing on $\mathbb R$. Does this mean that $f\cdot g$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb R$ ? If case it's not, what if $f$ and $g$ are positive (or negative) on  $\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: Try $f(x) = x$, $g(x) = x$.

Comment: @quasi What if $f$ and $g$ are positive ?

Comment: If $f,g$ are each increasing and also positive, then yes, the $f\cdot g$ is increasing.

Comment: @quasi And if they are both negative and increasing it also applies?

Comment: Apply the _definition_ of increasing. Suppose $f,g$ are increasing and positive. Suppose $a < b$. Then what can you say about $f(a)$ and $f(b)$? Same question for $g(a)$ and $g(b)$. Can you multiply those inequalities? Positivity of $f,g$ is relevant for that last question.

Comment: You have more than enough hints. Try to finish it.